# How do I link a Wagtail custom form to its output?

Tags: wagtail

When a custom form is created in Wagtail, I can see that it stores in the DB. What I'm not clear on is how to make it so that the ***admin*** UI contains the results in some manner. (A new link which lets you download a CSV would be fine, but I don't see how to do that)

How do I allow admin users the ability to see the results of the custom forms? Is [this library](https://github.com/ababic/wagtailmodeladmin) the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create your first form page (i.e. a page of any page type that subclasses `AbstractForm`), a 'Forms' item will automatically appear in the left menu of the Wagtail admin. This provides a listing of all the form pages that exist on the site, allowing you to access the results of each one and download them as a CSV.

Comment: ... Not sure how I missed that.